# Java memory leak after each file is opened

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

My application has the issue, that each time I load an image it increases it's RAM usage.

## Explanation

I create one frame with `JButton` with passed `GenericListener`. Once the `JButton` is clicked, it prompts file select, then it loads the file to a newly created `BufferedImage` and `GenericListener` `onExecute` method is called.

Such method creates instance of new class, let's call it `ImageProcessor`. Now the `SwingWorker` is created (still in the `GenericListener`) and calls some expensive methods in `doInBackground` method, then it returns the field stored in `ImageProcessor` which is acquired in `done` method and passed to an `ImageView` to update displayed image.

## Code

```
public abstract class GenericListener<T> implements EventListener {
    abstract void onExecute(T param);
}
```

JButton

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ...
            try {
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
                listener.onExecute(img);
            } 
        ...
    }
```

Listener's implementation

```
final ImageProcessor imp = new ImageProcessor(param);
new SwingWorker<BufferedImage, Object>() {
    @Override
    protected BufferedImage doInBackground() throws Exception {    
        return imp.doSomeExpensiveStuff();
    }

    @Override
    protected void done()
    {
        try {
            imgView.changeImage(get());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }
}.execute();
```

## Final Question

How can I make the application to free previously reserved memory space in order to load the new image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to free the memory from the stored variable just set it to null.

In your case you'd need to keep the `img` somewhere, probably with a final modifier (because anonymous calls must be performed on final fields).

```
img = null;
```

And the memory will be freed with a next GC :)

Answer (score 0):

These should be getting garbage collected, but they aren't, so this means you are holding onto a reference of the image somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value to null to make sure it's no longer reference and then manually call the garbage collector (System.gc).  You can also use jconsole to get an idea of how the memory is being used.   If you need more information then a heap dump and analysis of it will tell you what objects aren't being let go.

More info on trouble shooting memory leaks: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html#gbyvi